# How can I get around a dragon’s blindsight?

Tags: dnd-5e, dragons, vision-and-light

Does anyone know any legit ways to get around blindsight?

With Tremorsense, it has a built in way to get around it.

> A monster with tremorsense can detect and pinpoint the origin of
>       vibrations within a specific radius, provided that monster and the
>       source of the vibrations are in contact with the same ground or substance.
>       Tremorsense can't be used to detect flying or incorporeal creatures.

You can simply fly or cast levitate on yourself to become an unseen attacker.

However, with Blindsight...

> A creature with blindsight can perceive its surroundings without
>       relying on sight, within a specific radius. Creatures without eyes,
>       such as oozes, and creatures with echolocation or heightened senses,
>       such as bats and true dragons, have this sense.

There doesn't seem to be a good way to become an unseen attacker unless you cast *Etherealness*, but I was hoping for a way do get around it without casting such a high level spell.

Possibly casting *Prestidigitation* to have a heavy perfume scent in their nose. *Thunder clap* for something that hears too well. Or something of a similar sort.

Using an Adult Dragon as our example, how would you get around this?

Comment: Do you mean to be able to *hide* from it?

Comment: Taking the hide action out of the equation, because the hide action posits that you have something to hide behind. Unfortunately that can't always be the case. What I'm aiming for is being able to see them without them being able to see me, granting me advantage on the attack roll, and them disadvantage.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Stay out of range

Blindsight for an Adult Dragon has a 60 ft range only. Most spells and ranged weapons have higher ranges than that, so blindsight isn't actually a problem most of the time.

By your spell options, you are probably playing a Spellcaster, so you shouldn't be getting that close to a dragon to begin with.

### If you are melee, well, to be fair you don't

But Dragons aren't actually blind. If you are melee, the dragon would probably see you anyway, blindsight or not. I'm assuming your goal is to attack, as indicated by your question in

> to become an unseen attacker.

Hiding behind total cover would not allow you to attack the dragon either, so you are not an unseen attacker.

Answer (score 15):

### Just Hide Behind Something Solid

Jeremy Crawford has [stated](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/844028864191913985):

> If you're behind total cover, you're out of the blindsight's radius.

Jeremy Crawford also did confirm that blindsight would let the dragon see you if you were concealed by [something that only works on sight](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/976901520800141312) like a Darkness spell, mist, or smoke. But if you are behind total cover, you could still hide as usual.

Comment: This answer completely works, however having total cover comes with the disadvantage of not being able to see your target as well..